# How to get page from other server in php exist on same LAN?

Tags: php

Hi guys I am very new to php.I want to achieve a following task ,can anyone please help me out:

**Scenerio:**
I have created 4 pages in php named as splash.php,login-failure.php,login-successful.php,logout.php. Actually we are working on portal server and except splash.php my all the other three pages are present in other server and on same LAN. Firstly splash.php will be displayed and upon clicking a button I need to navigate to other pages depending upon the condition. So the question I need to write an script which allows me to access those pages which are present in other server.

I hope it would be clear.Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Comment: Which server are the scripts supposed to run on exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pages are not in the same computer (doesn't matter which network) then if you want the contents of those pages you need to use "curl". If you want to redirect the page to a different page I would use the "location" header, but there are other ways to redirect.